# Joda Time Returns Correct Date, but Java Time Doesn't

Tags: java, jodatime, java-time

I support a large enterprise app and we have two classes that use LocalDate.now to get a timestamp, one uses joda time, one uses Java time. Typically we restart every night, but earlier this week we weren't able to. On the second day of the application running, the class using joda time returned the correct date (20200505) but the class using Java time returned the date the application was turned on (20200504).

Both classes make a new call to LocalDate.now in the method each time it's called.

Java time:

```
String date = LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"));
//Use timestamp
```

Joda time:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
String format1 = date.toString("MM/dd/yyyy");
//Use date
```

Why does the Java 8 implementation of LocalDate.now return the wrong date after the server date has changed without an application restart?

Comment: Are the applications running on two different host?

Comment: I doubt this is a code issue and question your setup. Both classes use the information available from the system clock. If the system clock says it is still the 4-th then Java (and Joda) will return 4-th. Especially since it is `LocalDate` and thus not including any timezones.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and include a [mcve]?

Comment: Both no-arg `LocalDate.now` methods (java.time and Joda-Time) use the default time zone (it is never the same date in all time zones). It is possible to set Joda-Time’s default `DateTimeZone` to differ from the default time zone of the JVM, which may be one possible explanation for the difference observed (though maybe not the most likely one?).

Comment: The classes are within the same application, processing different file types. The host uses the eastern time zone, but the failure with Java time happened around 2 pm the 2nd day, so even if Java time was using a weird time zone, it should have been past the date change.  The server time is accurate in EST, as our logging shows the correct time stamps.

Answer (score 1):

The class with the issue is an enum, and it turns out in another call the value of a field in the enum was being changed and saved, so when the app was doing the timestamp replacement, the placeholder was no longer in the enum after the first call. Who knows why. Fixing this fixed the issue, no problem with Java time.

Answer (score 0):

The local date depends on the **default time zone**, as there is no global date.
I assume that the time zone in your server is off, and this still returns yesterday's date for a few hours after midnight. This is a quite common configuration error when configuring the server to run in UTC whilst the actual timezone is more on the eastern side.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault--

> If the cached default TimeZone is available, its clone is returned.
>   Otherwise, the method takes the following steps to determine the
>   default time zone.
>
> - Use the user.timezone property value as the default time zone ID if it's available.
> - Detect the platform time zone ID. The source of the platform time zone and ID mapping may vary with implementation.
> - Use GMT as the last resort if the given or detected time zone ID is unknown.

You can easily verify that by getting the `LocalDate.now()` after changing the default time zone:

```
TimeZone defaultTimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
try {
    Arrays.stream(TimeZone.getAvailableIDs())
        .map(TimeZone::getTimeZone)
        .forEach(timeZone -> {
            TimeZone.setDefault(timeZone);
            System.out.printf("%s in %s (%s)\n",
                LocalDate.now(), timeZone.getID(), timeZone.getDisplayName());
        });
} finally {
    TimeZone.setDefault(defaultTimeZone);
}
```

So the question is: **which time zone does your server use**?

Comment: Our server uses EST.  Even if we were configured to use UTC, wouldn't we expect the date to be there following day (after 7 pm), not the previous day?